# How to get the current URL of a Sharepoint ListItem in an itemAdded EventReceiver?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

On an itemAdded event in an EventReceiver (c#) I want to retrieve the full URL to the ListItem that was just saved.

I have tried:

SPContext.Current.Web.Url

However, this only returns the URL of the site as opposed to the ListItem.

How can I get the full URL to the ListItem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are given an SPItemEventProperties in the ItemAdded method.  This gives you a property named ListItem.  This will give you a Url property that will be the site-relative url to the list item.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    var itemPath = properties.ListItem.Url;
    // ...
}
```